# Efficiently marshaling large JSON data into structs with custom types

Tags: json, performance, go, memory-management, unmarshalling

I'm working on a Go application where I need to efficiently marshal a large JSON dataset into structs. The dataset contains complex nested structures and custom types. I've encountered performance issues when dealing with particularly large JSON files.

The JSON structure is as follows (simplified for brevity):

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Example",
        "details": {
          "type": "customType",
          "info": "Some info"
        }
      }
    }
    // More items...
  ]
}
```

I've defined corresponding Go structs, including a custom type for handling specific fields:

```golang
type DataSet struct {
    Data []DataItem `json:"data"`
}

type DataItem struct {
    ID         string     `json:"id"`
    Attributes Attributes `json:"attributes"`
}

type Attributes struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Details Detail `json:"details"`
}

type Detail struct {
    Type CustomType `json:"type"`
    Info string     `json:"info"`
}

// CustomType with custom unmarshaling logic
type CustomType string

func (ct *CustomType) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // Custom unmarshaling logic
}
```

The issue arises when marshaling large datasets with the json.Unmarshal function, leading to high memory usage and slow performance.

Are there more efficient techniques in Go for handling large JSON datasets with custom unmarshaling logic?

Could the struct design be optimized to improve the performance of JSON unmarshaling?

Go version: 1.18. The JSON files range from 100 MB to 1 GB in size. I've considered using streaming JSON parsers, but I'm unsure how to integrate with custom types.

I've tried the following.

- Standard json.Unmarshal with the provided struct setup.
- Experimented with reducing the depth of nested structs.

Comment: If you are looking for an external package - https://github.com/json-iterator/go is known to be really fast when dealing with streaming decode and exposes an API that is compatible with the standard library's encoding/json package.  Or if you want to run bleeding edge, the Go team is working on an experimental json package to be added into the standard library in the future releases - https://github.com/go-json-experiment/json and a related benchmark comparison with json-iter and other packages - https://github.com/go-json-experiment/jsonbench

Comment: Reading about `go-json-experiment/json` makes me realize my previous commnt was incorrect.  "json.NewEncoder and json.NewDecoder appear to offer streaming benefits, but this is mostly an idiomatic advantage, not a performance one, as internal buffering still takes place... when reading a large JSON object: you cannot begin processing the result until the entire result is received.".